# Android: How to select a specific libc++_shared.so file using packaging options?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am working on a project that contains three different NDK dependencies. All of them are build using different NDK versions and have their own `libc++shared.so` files. Since the NDK versions are different, I want to pick the `so` file that is compatible with all three. When I use the pickFirsts method it selects the wrong `so` file to build. I have tried doing it by the exclude method but it is not building and showing an error. Is there any other way to specify to `packagingOptions` about which `so` file to choose to pick?